# Inflection point at Vertical tangent?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

In Wikipedia and many other places, it is stated that $f''(a)=0$ is a necessary condition for a function to have an inflection point at $x=a$.

I was wondering, if a function had a vertical tangent, would an inflection point also exist there?

For example, let $f(x)=x^{1/3}(x-1)$,

$f'(x)=\frac 4 3 x^{1/3} - \frac 1 3 x^{-2/3} $ which has a root only at $x=1/4$ and for $x=0$, it has a vertical tangent.

$f''(x) = \frac 4 9 x^{-2/3} + \frac 2 9 x^{-5/3}$ which has a root only at $x=-1/2$.

By *nth* derivative test or by observing that $f''(x)$ changes sign in the neighborhood of $-1/2$ we conclude that $x=-1/2$ is an Inflection point.

But on drawing the graph of $f(x)$, we observe that even $x=0$ is an inflection point, where the nature of the function changes from concave down to concave up.

So is my assertion true that it is not necessary for the double derivative of a function to be $0$, to have an inflection point, provided a vertical tangent exists at that point?

Comment: Wikipedia states *If the second derivative, $f'' (x)$ exists at $x_0,$ and $x_0$ is an inflection point for $f,$ then $f'' (x_0) = 0\dots$*. One cannot ignore the context. The statement is true under constraint that $f$ is twice differentiable (of the class $C^2$) at that point. The functions in your examples do not satisfy this constraint. *The derivative exists* signifies that its value is a real number, not infinity - as in a case of vertical tangent.